# Add css attributes to menu_local_action Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I try to add extra class attributes to menu_local_action link, but it has not any effects.
How can I add this extra class

```
$items['jobs/maintenance/csv/import'] = array(
 'title' => t('Import CSV backup file'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('import_csv_form'),  
  'access arguments' => array('maintenance vip_advertiser'),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'bt', 'import'), //??
  'file' => 'maintenance.forms.inc',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
  'weight' => -3,
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Drupal 7 the class property is expecting an *array*:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => array('bt', 'import')),
```

Comment: Tanks Guys, 
Unfortunately none of them work from this solutions. Maybe this things are not supported for 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,

Comment: Ohhh sorry, didn't notice that was a menu hook. You can't add attributes there it has to be done at the theme level. Take a peek at how the [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module does it for inspiration (or just install that if it's easier)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this function theme_menu_local_action(). You can add preprocess to this theme hook and
add `'attributes' => array('class' => array('bt', 'import'))` in `$variables['element']['#link']['localized_options']`

Answer (score -1):

You should change your menu item definition and use

```
'options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => 'bt import'))
```

instead of this

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'bt', 'import')
```